# Can I change the username of a mobile worker via bulk uploads in CommCare?

Tags: commcare

I need to add an integer to every mobile worker in my project space. If I navigate to the "Users" and then "Mobile Workers" tab and try to edit one mobile worker, the field for username is not editable. Can I edit these usernames en masse via a bulk upload?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can modify the username using bulk upload. The caveat being that it will not update the username anywhere else on CommCareHQ. For example if `test1` submits a form, and then you change the username to `test2`, reports and exports will still say that `test1` has submitted the datum. The user id will remain the same.